# I want to add edit text field below by clicking button

Tags: java, android

I am new to android can u help me what code i need to write in button click listener.

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){@Overridepublic void onClick(View v)
   {

   });
```

Comment: Add the View in XML, set its visibility to invisible and inside your ClickListener set it's visibility to visible. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Comment: Kindly do some research before asking any question here.. :)